# Giving peak number to the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following script which reads the ascii file of two columns and generates 1D plot. The graph has several peaks. What I want is to give all the peak a number like first peak 1, second peak 2 and so on. The peaks appear in an equidistant position in X axis. Can someone tell me how to do that in python. The code-

```
from pylab import*


# Read the file. 
f2 = open('d012_SAXS-recomb.txt', 'r')

# read the whole file into a single variable, which is a list of every row of the file.
lines = f2.readlines()[2:-100]

f2.close()


# initialize some variable to be lists:
x1 = []

y1 = []


# scan the rows of the file stored in lines, and put the values into some variables:
for line in lines:

    p = line.split()

    x1.append(float(p[0]))

    y1.append(float(p[1]))


x = np.array(x1)

y = np.array(y1)


xlim(0.0,4.0)


# now, plot the data:
#subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, color='orange',linewidth=2.0, linestyle='-', label='Arabic - LPP''\nRoman - SPP''\nAsterisk - CHOL')
legend(loc='upper right')

xlabel('q')

ylabel('Intensity')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you talking about finding how to calculate the correct position to use pyplot.text() to place some text, like "peak1", "peak2" etc? The syntax is pyplot.text(x,y,string).

Comment: Does your question pertain more towards how to find the peaks, or is it more related as to how to place the text?

Comment: The pyplot.text can do it but in that case I have to manually give the x,y coordinate for each peak to put the number 1,2,3 on top of it. Are there any way by which in can automatically find the peak height and put the number like 1,2,3 on top of the peak?

Comment: Without knowing all the details of your data I don't know the easiest way to find all the peaks you require (or what threshold etc is the criteria for a "peak"), but I can give you an easy answer for the first (or highest peak). Since you say the peaks are equidistant on the x axis then the others should be easy to find by restricting (slicing) the data accordingly and searching the peak of the restricted sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code that finds the first (highest) peak. (BTW, I'm using pylab here, so the plot and numpy modules are already imported).

```
x = linspace(0,10,501)
y = exp(-0.2*x)*sin(x)
k = y.argmax()
plot(x,y)
text(x[k],y[k],'Peak1')
```

Try that to get started.